# How to configure Windows to trust a network share using a GPO?

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy

I keep getting the following warning whenever I try to open a share from my DFS.
[image: warning msg]

How can I configure Windows (10 in this case) to trust anything under the root of my DFS via GP?

It seems odd that it wouldn't do so automatically.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/149056/disable-these-files-might-be-harmful-to-your-computer-warning - Check the fourth answer down - how to remedy via group policy.

Comment: ^ This Q&A has all the information that you need to know!

Answer (score 5):

*While the related SuperUser [question](https://superuser.com/questions/149056/disable-these-files-might-be-harmful-to-your-computer-warning) has many solutions for this, they are mostly from the user's perspective: even the solution related to group policy uses Local Group Policy Editor and is far behind the accepted solution. Therefore, I'll just add a quick answer on how to do this for the whole network.*

**Create a GPO and enable three settings.** Related descriptions and values explained in citations.

Both *Computer Configuration* and *User Configuration* has these:

- Policies \ Administrative Templates \ Windows Components \ Internet Explorer

  - Internet Control Panel

    - Security Page
    - **Intranet Zone Template** > Enabled > Low

      > This template policy setting allows you to configure policy settings
      >   in this zone consistent with a selected security level, for example,
      >   Low, Medium Low, Medium, or High.
      >
      > If you enable this template policy setting and select a security
      >   level, all values for individual settings in the zone will be
      >   overwritten by the standard template defaults.
    - **Site to Zone Assignment List** > Enabled > Show...

      - Valuename = `yourserver`

        > A host for an intranet site, or a fully qualified domain name for
        >   other sites. The valuename may also include a specific protocol. For
        >   example, if you enter `http://www.contoso.com` as the valuename, other
        >   protocols are not affected. If you enter just `www.contoso.com`, then
        >   all protocols are affected for that site, including http, https, ftp,
        >   and so on. The site may also be expressed as an IP address (e.g.,
        >   `127.0.0.1`) or range (e.g., `127.0.0.1-10`).
      - Value = `1` (Intranet zone)
    - Intranet Zone

      - **Show security warning for potentially unsafe files** > Enabled > Enable

        > If you enable this policy setting and set the drop-down box to Enable,
        >   these files open without a security warning. If you set the drop-down
        >   box to Prompt, a security warning appears before the files open.